# Canon LBP6030W: Printing still in process but no jobs queued

Tags: printing

first, I appreciate the time you spent reading this and helping me.
**What happened:**
- I printed a 20-ish-pages document via wifi. Half way through the printing, my printer ran out of paper. Then, I took a look at Devices>Printers and found out **there's NO active job.**
['no active jobs shown'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kabMb.png)
- Meanwhile, the out of paper indicator on the printer was still flashing. Pressing it resumed the job, as I expected.
**The problem:**
- How can I cancel ***a print job that is half-way finished*** while there is no job listed in Devices>Printers?
**My inspection:**
- When I sent a print order, I did see the printer recieved the job (in Devices>Printer). But it only showed that for roughly 3 seconds before turning back to 'no active jobs'.
**What I tried:**
- `lprm` returned `lprm: No active jobs on (my printer name)`
- `sudo service cups restart`: Nothing changes.
- localhost:631/jobs shown all the jobs were finished
['all jobs completed'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvEwp.png)
**My system**
Thinkpad L390, dual-boot Windows 10 1909 and Ubuntu 19.10
****EDIT

*Hope the following info helps*

`service cups status`

```
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-03-02 11:55:00 +07; 17min ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
 Main PID: 1044 (cupsd)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 9.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           ├─1044 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
           ├─1178 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           ├─1179 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           ├─1180 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           └─1181 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://

Mar 02 11:55:00 Thinkpad-L390-LS systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
```

`ps -fu lp`

```
ID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lp        1178  1044  0 11:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus
lp        1179  1044  0 11:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus
lp        1180  1044  0 11:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus
lp        1181  1044  0 11:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus
```

`lpstat -t`

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: Canon-LBP6030-6040-6018L
device for Canon-LBP6030-6040-6018L: socket://192.168.1.6
Canon-LBP6030-6040-6018L accepting requests since Mon 02 Mar 2020 09:18:25 +07
printer Canon-LBP6030-6040-6018L is idle.  enabled since Mon 02 Mar 2020 09:18:25 +07
```

Content from `var/log/cups/error_log` as follow

```
E [01/Mar/2020:23:15:27 +0700] [Client 54] Returning IPP client-error-document-format-not-supported for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/LBP6030w-6018w) from localhost.
E [01/Mar/2020:23:17:14 +0700] [Client 9] Returning IPP client-error-document-format-not-supported for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/LBP6030w-6018w) from localhost.
W [01/Mar/2020:23:28:00 +0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'LBP6030w-6018w-Gray..\' already exists
E [01/Mar/2020:23:40:39 +0700] [Client 32] Returning IPP client-error-document-format-not-supported for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/LBP6030w-6018w) from localhost.
W [01/Mar/2020:23:55:06 +0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'LBP6030-6040-6018L-Gray..\' already exists
E [02/Mar/2020:00:01:44 +0700] [Client 110] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/5) from localhost.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:01:51 +0700] [Client 112] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/4) from localhost.
W [02/Mar/2020:00:03:19 +0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'LBP6030-6040-6018L-Gray..\' already exists
E [02/Mar/2020:00:17:30 +0700] Scheduler shutting down due to program error.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:17:53 +0700] Scheduler shutting down due to program error.
X [02/Mar/2020:00:18:11 +0700] No valid Listen or Port lines were found in the configuration file.
X [02/Mar/2020:00:18:11 +0700] No valid Listen or Port lines were found in the configuration file.
X [02/Mar/2020:00:18:11 +0700] No valid Listen or Port lines were found in the configuration file.
X [02/Mar/2020:00:18:11 +0700] No valid Listen or Port lines were found in the configuration file.
X [02/Mar/2020:00:18:11 +0700] No valid Listen or Port lines were found in the configuration file.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:26:18 +0700] Scheduler shutting down due to program error.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:27:43 +0700] Scheduler shutting down due to program error.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:32:03 +0700] [Client 17] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost:631/printers/LBP6030-6040-6018L) from localhost.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:43:32 +0700] [Job 18] The printer is not responding.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:44:02 +0700] [Job 18] The printer is not responding.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:44:32 +0700] [Job 18] The printer is not responding.
E [02/Mar/2020:00:45:59 +0700] [Client 242] Request from "localhost" using invalid Host: field "[v1.::1]:631".
E [02/Mar/2020:00:45:59 +0700] [Job 16] Unable to queue job for destination "LBP6030-6040-6018L".
E [02/Mar/2020:08:34:35 +0700] [Job 16] Files have gone away.
E [02/Mar/2020:09:18:31 +0700] [Client 56] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/20) from localhost.
E [02/Mar/2020:09:20:01 +0700] [Client 61] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/20) from localhost.
E [02/Mar/2020:09:34:21 +0700] [Client 65] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon-LBP6030-6040-6018L) from localhost.
E [02/Mar/2020:09:35:30 +0700] [Client 66] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon-LBP6030-6040-6018L) from localhost.
W [02/Mar/2020:10:54:17 +0700] Notifier for subscription 181 (dbus://) went away, retrying!
W [02/Mar/2020:10:54:17 +0700] Notifier for subscription 183 (dbus://) went away, retrying!
W [02/Mar/2020:10:54:17 +0700] Notifier for subscription 187 (dbus://) went away, retrying!
```

Comment: `service cups status`, `ps -fu lp`, `lpstat -t`, will all help figure out what's happening. Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/1214185/edit your post to add info. Also look at `/var/log/cups/*`

Comment: @waltinator Thank you! I've edited the post  with the information from the commands.

Comment: remember the printer also has a queue. So once your computer queue has been sent to the printer, you will no longer see anything in the printer queue...

Comment: @RoryAlsop. Much appreciated your comment!
Yeah, I guessed just about so. However, it would be nice if we could somehow control the printer's queue right. I mean, it is sure possible on Windows.
Anyhow, I figured out that physically restart the printer also cancel its queue.